# Bitwise Or with 0

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Bitwise Operators are pretty interesting so I tried figuring out a way to have the opposite effect of or, but not the effect of xor.

If I have two chars (8 bit):

```
char1    char2
=====    =====
1010     1000

after transformation

1000     1000
```

If `0010` is the value I want to transfer char1 and char2 to disable at that registrar (position 1)

How would I do that?

`or` only sets 1 if 1 and 1, and `xor` only swaps values if 1 and 0 or 0 and 1

Comment: xor will give 1 when the bits are different... it doesn't "swap" them exactly.  So `1010` xor'ed with `1000` gives `0010`... is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for not being elaborate. 1010 something 0010 should give the value 1000, in addition 1000 and 0010 should give 1000

Comment: @MysteryDev Those are contradicting requirements, or the operator you are looking for is not a built-in one, all of which are **symmetric.**

Comment: Are you just trying to zero a specified bit if it's set?  In that case, you want to NOT the second value, then AND... `x & ~y`

Comment: @Dmitri thank you! that was so hard to explain.

Comment: To solve these sorts of problems in the future try writing a "truth table". That is, suppose the relation is called `#`. Now write down all the cases; there are only four. You want `1#1=0`, `1#0=1`, `0#1=0` and `0#0=0`.  Now look at that. There's only a single `1` as the output. There is only one condition in which `a#b` is 1, and that is if *`a` is 1 and `b` is 0*.  Now it is easy to see that you want `a and not b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite of *or* is *and-not*. You can use *or* to set bits, and  *and-not* to clear bits.

```c
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    int a = 16, b, c;

    // Set bit 3
    b = a | 1<<3; // OR
    assert(b == (8+16));


    // Clear bit 3
    c = b & ~(1<<3); // AND-NOT
    assert(c == 16);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want `& (and)`:

```
1100 & 1010 = 1000
```

It's often used with inversion to set specific bits to 0.

```
1100 & ~0100 = 1100 & 1011 = 1000
```